# articles in variable names and hard-coding strings

Tags: java, programming-practices, coding-style, coding-standards

re-edited by author: no this is not 2 questions. This is one question about code review questions containing two separate points. Please do not edit my question.

For naming variables, the two sides are regarding using articles (a, an, the) in the variable name (e.g. theBook vs. book -or- parseTheString vs. parseString).

For hard-coding strings, the three sides are whether to put all strings into constants (public static final) in a separate file (class or interface), put them all in the same file (private static final), or don't use constants for strings at all. (e.g. new Button("Click Me")  vs.  new Button(BUTTON_LABEL_CLICK)).  We also discuss the Hungarian notation issue quite a bit but I've seen that discussed here in other questions.

For a very long time it has been the defacto standard to not use articles in variable names (adds visual clutter without adding value) and to not have hard-coded strings sprinkled through the source code (a potential maintenance nightmare and very poor for internationalization). Now we are starting to see violations of these and the developers seem truly surprised when someone marks these as defects or at least needing attention. The manager has said they don't care one way or the other and these points are not in our company coding standards.

Comment: why not ask two separate questions instead of bundling two for one?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Articles in Variable Names

**They add little to no value in most cases, but make the code longer to read.**

Usually, I'd rarely have a the need for the distinction between a "a" or "the" in the flow of a function, so it doesn't make sense to use articles.

It's a formal programming language and I am fine with it not reading exactly like a natural language. In fact, it's probably better this way, not everything's necessarily so great about natural languages.

There are a few cases where readability can benefit from using articles though, for instance if you want to implement a checker for a "is a" relationship with a method signature like `boolean isA(Object o, Class<?> cl)` <sup>(I'm not advocating this to be a good idea)</sup>.

## Hard-Coded Strings

It depends on whether you plan to reuse them or not, and whether that reuse is driven by semantics (and not just the fact that the String has the same content in different places) and spread across multiples classes or sub-systems.

To that extent, I usually use these rules:

1. If you have the same string multiple times and it has the same meaning acros multiple classes, then extract to constants in an interface.
2. If you have the same string multiple times within a single class and it has the same meaning within that class, then extract to constants within the class.
3. If you have only a few number of repetitions of as tring, or they just happen to be identical but aren't guaranteed to always be in the future, then I'd leave them inlined.
4. If any of the above would render maintenance difficult, screw rules 1 to 3 and do whatever works best for you.

Of course, make sure that the constant's name makes the code as semantically valid as the string it holds. That also applies for other things that aren't strings (like Predicates, for instance).

Comment: hard coded strings makes for very difficult internationalisation - but if this isn't even a long term goal (ie, you know that your market will always be limited to one language) then it isn't much of a problem.

Comment: @HorusKol: you mean when they're extracted to an interface? I don't find that either approach makes it easier or harder for I18N in general. The only annoyance with I18N is that usually you'll end up with the "key" Strings that aren't necessarily aptly named, and that's when the semantics get lost and you don't know what you're looking at anymore. Also, you then need to convey to your analysis tools that these strings are meant to be here and shouldn't be extracted to constants or other things because they're just keys anyways.

Comment: @haylem - yes I agree that "isa" and "hasa" are special cases for the "articles" rule.

Comment: @haylem - re hard-coded strings: you make reasonable points but we must also consider that we cannot predict the future. We may know what is intended now re how it is to fit into the world. The future is unknowable with certainty so for long-living code, it is most flexible and easiest to maintain/re-fit/upgrade by making as many things as possible (key phrase there) as flexible as we can. Having to edit one or a few fairly small classes as opposed to picking through tens of thousands of lines of code (grep notwithstanding) and hope you got them all - the difference is clear to me at least.

Comment: @Iceberg: It's true that you can't predict the future, so be careful not to plan unnecessarily for it. Quite likely, [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAGNI). Sometimes, it's more cost-effective, even on the long term, to focus on what you need for now rather than what you may need later. All depends on your project of course, but we don't know what you aim for here.

Comment: One use for articles is as a scope indication, when used as a prefix: `a` for function/method arguments, `the` for globals/class statics.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau: Seems valid, but not very common. I still consider this doesn't add much value. To each their own.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau I saw that various times and in general I consider it a very poor convention. It is better to add a letter (e.g. `p` as parameter) or an underscore for parameters because using articles in parameters doesn't make sense (you would actually also have to add `an`). Using such things for globals/class statics is terrible.

Answer (score 2):

> For hard-coding strings, the three sides are whether to put all strings into constants (public static final) in a separate file (class or interface), put them all in the same file (private static final), or don't use constants for strings at all. (e.g. new Button("Click Me") vs. new Button(BUTTON_LABEL_CLICK)). We also discuss the Hungarian notation issue quite a bit but I've seen that discussed here in other questions.

If you want a high-quality user experience, anything that is presented to the user (button labels, error messages, etc.) must be reviewed by the UI designer.  In my experience, when developers are hard-coding text, that doesn't happen.  The developers do the best they can, but the result is a set of messages and labels that are little better than random.

Comment: another good point. And when the text is mandated to change? much harder and more time consuming to make it so.
Thanks everyone. It's good to hear the different viewpoints.

Answer (score 1):

Apple [use articles](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001282-1001751-BCIJHEDH) - inconsistently - in their ObjC code.  It adds *nothing* to the legibility of their code or the descriptiveness of their variable names:

```
- (id)viewWithTag:(NSInteger)aTag;
- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frameRect mode:(int)aMode cellClass:(Class)factoryId numberOfRows:(int)rowsHigh numberOfColumns:(int)colsWide;
```

Note `aTag` and `aMode` vs `frameRect`.

I hate the semi-standard and don't use it.  It makes the code sound moronic.